# Rails : How to assign name and id to hidden_field_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, hidden-field

How to assign specific id and name to hidden_field_tag ?

Like this,

```
hidden_field_tag(:id => "page_no",:name => "page", :value => "1" )
```

Any Idea!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
hidden_field_tag("page_name", "1", :id => "page_no")
```

per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag

Answer (score 9):

It takes `hidden_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})`

So the third parameter is for options.

`hidden_field_tag("page", "1", {:id => "page_no"})` would set name to "page", value to "1" and id to "page_no"

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass first parameter as name, and second as value.
Also, you can override the name of the parameters like this.

```
  <%=hidden_field_tag :param_name, 'param_value', {:id => 'ashish_id', :name => 'another_name'}%>
```

Comment: Good on 'ya for the override.  Useful for cases like `:name => 'movement[user_id]'`